# Adding to a non-existent array in a collection with $addToSet

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This should be very simple. I have two collections, one of which holds two types of data (name, age), and the other should simply add the age values to an array (with no duplicates).

I "start" my collections like usual:

```
People = new Mongo.Collection('people')
Ages = new Mongo.Collection('ages')
```

Right now I'm working with seed data, but the question could easily extend to when I actually want to dynamically add data to the array. I seed it like so:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

  if (People.find().count() === 0) {
    [
      {
        name: 'John',
        age: '24' //Yes, I want to store it as strings.
      },
      { ... } //more data
    ]
    .forEach(function(person) {
      People.insert(person)
      Ages.update({ $addToSet: {age: person.age}}) //Not working
    })
  }
})
```

That last part there is what's not working. I guess I figured `$addToSet` would fix things for me, since the docs say:

> If the field is absent in the document to update, $addToSet creates
>   the array field with the specified value as its element.

Now I suppose I have to create the field first, but I'm not sure where or how. I have a strong, strong feeling that I'm overlooking something ridiculously simple here...

Comment: Maybe you change your title into: How to store distinct values by $addToSet into additional collection

Comment: @agm1984 Yes it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, your db should look like that when filled

Persons (_id, name, age)

1, John, 24
2, Pete, 21
3, Michele, 27
4, Sandy, 21

Ages (_id, ageset)

?, [ 24, 21, 27 ]

Solution1: Just insert one record on a fix key and then only update this one.

Have a look at [this MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/cHbbjreeqTfsto9wX/Playground_Peoples_and_Ages_by_distinct_set)

Solution2: Using a local Meteor.Collection which is synced by server an gets DISTINCT field values from package `mrt:mongodb-aggregation`.

Have a look at [this MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/8taGtxPCW8yFNiZcB/Playground_Peoples_and_Ages_by_server_sided_distinct_array)

Solution3: Using a server side synced Mongo.Collection to hold the distinct ages list.

Have a look at [this MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/KT2SviZSCBYB42Pz2/Playground_Peoples_and_Ages_by_server_synced_collection)

Remark: Checkout log infos on server process. There are timeouts to add, change and remove a record for test and updates (5 sec, 10 sec, 15 sec)

Comment: Yes. But you should use the comment section to ask questions. :)

Comment: I do not have enough points yet to add a comment - so decision was to ignore your post or write in the only available field ;-)

Comment: Thanks. This prints the entire array at once, doesn't it? It doesn't actually loop through it? The reason I didn't choose to store it as "normal" is because I think it's a bit overkill, and because `$addToSet` makes an array and I don't know how to avoid duplicates without it.

Comment: I updated with 2 more MeteorPad showing Meteor and Mongo Collection, hope that help

Comment: If Meteor would be able to use mongo distinct function it would be much easier than now

Comment: I added also iteration over array to solution1 MeteorPad

Answer (score 0):

Now right now, I see that you're defining your People collection, but I don't see you actually defining "**person**" or "**Age**" anywhere. Maybe thats just due to how you've formatted your answer.

Either way though, I'm not entirely sure you'd be getting anything to happen. As far as I know, you'll need to select the documents each time through the loop, as you want to update them.

This is how I'm doing something similar in an app I'm working on:

```
Meteor.users.update({ _id: Meteor.userId() }, { $addToSet: { 'profile.viewedRequests' : this._id }});
```

The key there being that I'm selecting an individual document, before attempting to update it.

Its either that, or you need to switch to People.update.

Comment: Don't know what you mean with not defining `person` or `Age`, but yes, `update()` needs an identifier, but I'm not sure where to get it. `insert()` doesn't work either. edit: I see what you mean now, just a type in my code here (Age should be Ages), not something that caused the error.